# Meaning of "all shelves about me towards the worse"?

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

> "Here am I now upon my high place," he said to himself. "Life may be no better; this is the mountain top; and **all shelves about me towards the worse.** For the first time I will light up the chambers, and bathe in my fine bath with the hot water and the cold, and sleep alone in the bed of my bridal chamber." *The Bottle Imp* by R.L. Stevenson, 1895

I simply can't figure out what this sentence means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From context, what I'm getting is that the subject is at the peak of what's good for his life, from here, his life can only get worse.

I believe the shelf he is talking about is a ridgeline or a cliff top or similar:

[image]

In this context, I think *either* he's using *shelve* as:

- a verb, in the sense of 'a ridgeline (a shelf) extends along'.
- a plural noun, in the sense that there are lots of these ridges. But in this case the sentence is gramatically incorrect, the sentence should be something like "all shelves about me [are pointed] towards the worse"

ie. He's at the top of the mountain at life, now all he can do is walk along these shelves towards a worse life.

Comment: The extract comes from a Robert Louis Stevenson short story, 'The Bottle Imp'.

Answer (score 4):

**Shelving** is usually something you say about a beach,  It slopes evenly down from the high tide line into the water, so you quickly get to swimming depth without stumbling.

This poor misery is on top of a metaphorical mountaintop that shelves away on each side. He has everything (including hot and cold running water **!** (in 1895) ) so what is there left to hope for.

> SHELVING (noun)  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shelving)
>    1 :  a sloping surface or
>   place
>    2 :  the state or degree of sloping

Here's the verb, just as it occurs in the book:

> Shelve (verb: 2) [origin obscure]
>
> 1. *intr.* Of a surface: To slope gradually 1652.
> 2. [obelised] to have an inclined position -1763.
> 3. *trans.* to tilt.
>
> source:Shorter Oxford 1933

Comment: This is a better answer than mine. :)

Comment: .... +1, good answer, Hugh. Do you intend "miser" as opposed to "misery"?

Comment: **Misery:** 1.2 [count noun] British informal A person who is constantly miserable or discontented: OxfDictionaries. But more usually people say  "misery guts".  And thanks @Little Eva.

Comment: "Misery"? For a person? That's a usage of "misery" I've never encountered previously. I'm still shaking my head at it.

Comment: @LittleEva In the 17th century *miserable* meant "capable of being shown mercy" or *pitiable* -- "Have mercy upon us miserable sinners," as the Book of Common Prayer has it. The meaning has morphed into *dejected*. There may be a question about *miserable, misery* [state], *misery* [person], especially when *miser=hoarder of money* is thrown into the mix.

Comment: @Andrew Leach - thank you Andrew. That's quite interesting, brand new stuff, for me. I had never made the now obvious connection between miserable and capable of mercy.

Answer (score 3):

This is from "The Bottle Imp" a story by Robert Louis Stevenson (actually first published in 1891), and "shelves" here is a verb meaning "to slope down and away from."  The *OED* says "gently," but one of the exemplars uses the word "precipitously."  The narrator has just fallen in love and thinks that he's reached the peak of happiness in his life and that everything must tilt toward the worse.  And he seems to be vindicated in that judgment since the next paragraph reveals that he's contracted leprosy.